# Convert Objective C Predicate in Swift 3

Tags: swift, predicate

I have to convert Objective C code in Swift. 
Here is my objective C code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FacilityId == %@ && Id != %@", facility[kColumnId], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kKeyUserId]];

return [[self coworkers] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;
```

And I converted it to swift. Here is my swift code.

```
let filteredCoworkers = self.coworkers.filter{

        $0["FacilityId"] as? Int == facility[kColumnId] as? Int && $0["Id"] as? String != UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: kKeyUserId)
    }
return filteredCoworkers.count
```

But its not working as I am getting empty filteredCoworkers array. It should not be empty. It means that filter is not working.

Comment: Please define "not working" so people know what to look for.

Comment: Define not working, what issue you are facing, Are you getting any error? if yes add that error in your question

Comment: I have edited my question. Filtering is not working.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should create a model type rather than using dictionaries here (then make `coworkers` an array of this model type). This will eliminate the string keys and casts, making your code strongly typed instead of *stringly* typed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "FacilityId == %@ && Id != %@", facility[kColumnId], (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: kKeyUserId) as? NSPredicate))
return self.coworkers.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }.count
```